# XPages Bootstrap tabs eventhandler

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, tabs, xpages, eventhandler

I am using Bootstrap tabs in my XPage application as follows:

```
<div class="bs-component">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active">
<a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">
PENDING REQUESTS
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">
ARCHIVES
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Upon clicking a given tab, I'd like to set a sessionScope variable. I tried substituting the li with an xp:panel (tagName="li") and an eventHandler attached but could not get it to write to sessionScope. I'm using Mark Leusink's debugger to check scope variables.

[image]

Would appreciate suggestions.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way it to add some JQuery code to add an onClick event, which triggers SSJS code. How to do this, see http://www.xpagetips.com/2011/11/running-ssjs-from-csjs-sometimes-its.html

Answer (score 0):

This code should work. You must set id attribute for panel

```
<xp:panel tagName="li" id="XXX">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.XXX = "";}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:panel>
```

For attach to ssjs event XSP use this code(example):

```
XSP.attachEvent("view:_id1:_id3:_id12", "view:_id1:_id3:image2", "onclick", null, true, 2);
```

Where second parameter is target id attribute

Comment: Thanks Roman. I did try exactly this and could not get it to work, probably because of the href that follows. How do I incorporate the following into your xp:panel example? <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">

Comment: What about change <a> to <xp:link>? And add server-side event to link